# Editar usuario de devise desde otro controlador rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, devise

quiero que los usuarios con el rol de admin, puedan editar los roles de los usuarios que no son admin, por eso cree otro conrolador con sus respectivas vistas pero cuando le doy a editar un usuario obtengo undefined method `user_path' for #<#:0x00007fece9d883c0>

Asi luce el controller:

```js
class AdminController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_admin, only: [:edit, :update] #importante agregar
    before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
    #load_and_authorize_resource
  def index
    user = params[:keyword]
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
    if user.present?
      @users = @users.where("name ILIKE ?",user)
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(admin_params)
  format.html { redirect_to admin_index_path, success: 'Actualizado' }
      else
  format.html { redirect_to admin_index_path, success: 'No se guardo' }
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def set_admin
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  
  def admin_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:id, :role)
  end

end
#edit.html.erb
<%form_for @user do |f|%>
<div class="field col-lg-6">
    <label class="label">Rol:</label>
    <% f.select :role, Roles: User.roles.keys.to_a %> 
   </div>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Pon el error completo, ahí te sale el archivo y la línea especifica donde se genera el error (que lo más probable es que sea en la vista)

Comment: Hola Gerry, gracias, ya lo solucione

Comment: Si encontraste una solución, sería aceptable que la agregues como respuesta, así puede servirle a alguien que eventualmente tenga tu mismo problema a futuro. Saludos (PD: No soy Gerry xD)

Comment: si tienes razon, ya publique la solucion! Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Gracias por sus respuesta: la solución abajo:

edit.html.erb

<%= form_for @user, url: admin_path(@user), html: { method: :put } do |f|%> 
 la linea del form_for fue la unica que cambie lo demas igual

Answer (score 0):

El error se podría estar generando desde el Router.

Verifica que el routes.rb tengas la linea

`resources :users`

Así como también tener todas las acciones en su respectivo controlador, en este caso sería un

`UsersController`

Esta linea habilitara todas la acciones crud para el model de User

Comment: Hola Cesar, gracias, ya lo solucione!